# Split Characters and Numbers

Tags: vb.net, split, format, currency

I have this problem in split

I want to convert the numeric into formatcurrency but it contains a Character

For example:

```
POC 1900
output :
POC $1,900.00
```

Or

```
    1900 POC 
    output :
    $1,900.00 POC
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expression to match and replace values.

```
Dim str = "1900 POC" //Or "POC 1900"
Dim reg = New Regex("\d+")

Dim match = reg.Match(str)
If match.Success Then
  str = reg.Replace(str, Decimal.Parse(match.Value).ToString("C"))
  Console.WriteLine(str)
End If
```

EDIT:

If string contains comma (,) between numbers then replace it with :

```
Dim str = "1,900 POC".Replace(",", "")
```

Comment: with '$' sign and the the amount?

Comment: Method Decimal.Parse(match.Value).ToString("C") will do and output would be `POC $1,900.00` or `$1,900.00 POC`

Comment: I try your code but some did generate wrong 
in my database its POC 1,420... then the output of it is POC $1.00,$1.00

Comment: Of course! You can replace the comma from string using `Dim str = "1,900 POC".Replace(",", "")`

Comment: ok thank you so much     If y = 0 Then
 Else
 Dim reg = New Regex("\d+")
Dim str As String = dZ.Rows(y).Item(14).ToString().Replace(",", "").Trim
 Dim match = reg.Match(str)
If match.Success Then
str = reg.Replace(str, Decimal.Parse(match.Value).ToString("C"))
                                End If
                                Amount += IIf(dZ.Rows(y).Item(13).ToString <> "" Or dZ.Rows(y).Item(14).ToString <> "", ";" + str.ToString().Trim, ";")
End If

Comment: have a big problem... what if 1,900.50 POC

Comment: @kelvzy What *possible* chars along with numbers including comma, period etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strValue As String = "POC 1900"
Dim strOutput As String = String.Empty
Dim strNum As String() = strValue .Split(" ")
Dim strDisplay As String = String.Empty
For x As Integer = 0 To strNum.Length - 1
   strDisplay = String.Concat(strDisplay, " ", IIf(IsNumeric(strNum(x)), FormatCurrency(Val(strNum(x)), 2), strNum(x)))
Next

strOutput = strDisplay
```

Comment: but what if my POC is in the end part?